# How to make tslint accept variable name with "_" at the beginning

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a require of customer that say to need `"_"` symbol. I added this like that:

```
public _someVariable: string;
```

but tslint say `variable name must be in lowerCamelCase, PascalCase or UPPER_CASE (variable-name)`.

I want remove alerts while keeping the tslint config and this is my tslint config:

```
"variable-name": {
  "options": [
    "ban-keywords",
    "check-format",
    "allow-pascal-case"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `allow-leading-underscore`.

```
"variable-name": {
  "options": [
    "ban-keywords",
    "check-format",
    "allow-pascal-case",
    "allow-leading-underscore"
  ]
},
```

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/variable-name/

Comment: Thank sir, I'm sorry for not having enough reputation to vote for your answer